# How to display top largest files in a non blocking manner on linux?

Tags: filesystems, diskspace

For years I have being using variasons of [`du`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/du-invocation.html) command below in order to produce a report of the largest files from specific location, and most of the time it worked well.

```
du -L -ch /var/log | sort -rh  | head -n 10 &> log-size.txt
```

This this proved to get stuck in several cases, in a way that prevented stopping it with even the `timeout -s KILL 5m ...` approach.

Few years back this was caused by stalled NFS mounts but more recently I got into this in on VMs where I didn't use NFS at all. Apparently there is a ~1:30 chance to get this on openstack builds.

I read that following symbolic links (`-L`) can block "du" in some cases if there are loops but my tests failed to reproduce the problem, even when I created some loop.

I cannot avoid following the symlinks because that's how the files are organized.

What would be safer alternative to generate this report, one that would not block or at least if it does, it can be constrainted to a maximum running duration. It is essential to limit the execution of this command to a number of minutes -- if I can also get a partial result on timeouts or some debuggin info even better.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about sparse files and can make do with apparent size (and not the on-disk size), then `ls` should work just fine: `ls -L --sort=s|head -n10> log-size.txt`

Comment: Clearly that command does not recurse into subdirs even after I added -R argument. So far I was not able to make ls work alone recursively, at least not in the desired behavior, where it will list *files* only.